# get/sum values from wildcard keys in redis

Tags: redis, nosql-aggregation, nosql

I have a string type key value store in redis having keys like this--

```
/url-pattern/url-slug-1
/url-pattern/url-slug-2
/url-pattern/url-slug-3
/url-pattern/url-slug-4 ...
```

I can retrieve all the keys of ***/url-pattern/*** using a wild card query like this --

```
keys /url-pattern/*
```

I would like to retrieve the values of all keys corresponding to this wildcard ***/url-pattern/****

I tried this

```
    mget /url-pattern/*
1) (nil)
```

but it doesnt returned the array as expected.

How can I retrieve the values of all keys corresponding to ***/url-pattern/****

I also want to do a sum on the values, but I think there is no such thing called SUM() in redis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MGET accepts multiple arguments where each a key name. It does not do key name patterns.

What you could do is first fetch all the relevant key names (**do not use KEYS**, use SCAN instead) and then fetch their values with an MGET.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an updated answer for 2015.

If you can upgrade Redis above 2.8, the SCAN command with MATCH will work for this. Before that version, not so much, and do NOT use the KEYS command except in a development environment.

http://redis.io/commands/scan

Example on command line:

```
$ redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> scan match V3.0:*
(error) ERR invalid cursor
127.0.0.1:6379> scan 0 match V3.0:*
1) "0"
2) 1) "V3.0:UNITTEST55660BC7E0C5B"
   2) "V3.0:shop.domain.com:route"
   3) "V3.0:UNITTEST55660BC4A2548"
127.0.0.1:6379> scan 0 match V1.0:*
1) "0"
2) (empty list or set)
127.0.0.1:6379> scan 0 match V3.0:*
1) "0"
2) 1) "V3.0:UNITTEST55660BC7E0C5B"
   2) "V3.0:shop.domain.com:route"
   3) "V3.0:UNITTEST55660BC4A2548"
```

Example in PHP:

```
// Initialize our iterator to NULL
$iterate = null;

// retry when we get no keys back
$redis->setOption(Redis::OPT_SCAN, Redis::SCAN_RETRY);

while ($arr_keys = $redis->scan($iterate, 'match:*')) {
    foreach ($arr_keys as $str_key) {
        echo "Here is a key: $str_key\n";
    }
    echo "No more keys to scan!\n";
}
```

Note, php code is not tested and from the core documentation for example here. Production code would need to be modified depending on the keys needed to look up.

For those on Ubuntu here are the instructions to upgrade php5-redis:

1. Download the 2.2.7 package here: http://pecl.php.net/package/redis
2. `$ php -i | grep Redis
   Redis Support => enabled
   Redis Version => 2.2.4`
3. Follow instructions in README to phpize, configure, make install
4. Create a symlink for command line cli package: `cd /etc/php5/cli/conf.d && sudo ln -s ../../mods-available/redis.ini 20-redis.ini`
5. `$ php -i | grep Redis
   Redis Support => enabled
   Redis Version => 2.2.7`

Comment: Additional note after we've run something like this for a while. Keep in mind, the scan still loops through the keys so this can have a performance impact.

Answer (score 0):

There is NO command available in REDIS which can return values from wildcard keys.

If you see the documentation for `KEYS` command: http://redis.io/commands/keys, it says

> Consider KEYS as a command that should only be used in production
>   environments with extreme care. It may ruin performance when it is
>   executed against large databases. This command is intended for
>   debugging and special operations. Don't use KEYS in your regular
>   application code.

I don't know your business use case, but looks like you may have to use different data structure for this requirement. You can use list or set to store similar url patterns.

Comment: Exactly and as of v2.8 use the SCAN command (et al) instead of KEYS - it lets you get at practically the same result as KEYS but in a polite, non-blocking manner.